# Rotate container with child elements

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I'm trying to reconstruct this [sidenav_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/squWZ.png)

This is my html and SCSS:

HTML:

```
<div class="sidenav-container">
  <div class="sidenav-item" *ngFor="let sidenavItem of sidenav">
    <span>{{ sidenavItem.text }}</span>
    <img [src]="sidenavItem.img" />
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.sidenav-container {
  position: absolute;

  .sidenav-item {
    align-items: flex-start;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    display: flex;

    img {
      width: 5px;
      height: auto;
    }

    span {
      font-size: 2.5pt;
    }
  }
}
```

If i do it like this i always get this result [my_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ67H.png)

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I don't fully understand but you can try to give the height 100vh

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

To 'sidenaev-container' class at your .scss

Comment: Thats for rotation, then adjust sizing and it should work